# Import several values for procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

**The setting**:

I currently have two tables, one with categories and one with products.
The categories have an ID and its parent´s ID, and the products include the ID to the category they belong too.

**What I need**

In order to reduce the amounts of requests I do to the database, I want to be able to import several ID to the procedure so I don't need to ask for the products for each child category.

**The question**

Is it possible to import several values (like a matrix) so I can get all the values or make a loop to identify the categories needed directly from MySQL?

Example:
[image]

**What I'm using**: Microsoft SQL Server and Visual Studio 2010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can use user-defined table types to pass a "matrix" of data to a stored procedure.  This is also a useful resource: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to investigate using a structured data type in Visual Studio, and a TABLE TYPE in SQL Server. You can build the the DataTable in your VS code, and then pass a DataTable as a Structured Data Type in a Stored Procedure. From there you can join to the TABLE TYPE, Insert from it, etc.

```
 DataTable dtMyDataTable= new DataTable("dtMyDataTable");
 dtMyDataTable.Columns.Add("Val1", typeof(bool));
 dtMyDataTable.Columns.Add("Val2", typeof(string));

 dtMyDataTable.Rows.Add(Param1, Param2); // Maybe add values in a loop in VS

  parameter = new SqlParameter();
  parameter.ParameterName = "@MyTableTypeSPParameter";
  parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
  parameter.Value = dtMyDataTable;
  cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Comment: Adding some links and clarity to this would make this a pretty good answer.